# "assign a category" or "assign to a category"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I translate technical documentation to English and we often have phrases like "system A is assigned (to) safety class/seismic category B". According to the rules of English grammar, in the Passive Voice the preposition is not needed with the word "class" i.e. "the system A is assigned class B", as, for example, in **Passive sentence 1** here https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/passive_two_objects.htm

The reverse order would be proper with the preposition: "class B is assigned to system A".
But in some documents in the internet (including American engineering sites) it is easy to find "the system A is assigned **to** class B". I am confused. Is the second type of sentence legit or just a common mistake?